# Fundamental Group of the special Euclidean matrix group of the plane

Tags: algebraic-topology

How do you do this?  Compute the fundamental group of the special Euclidean group of the plane, that is, all matrices of the form:  $
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(z) & \sin(z) & x \\
-\sin(z) & \cos(z)& y \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right)$

I don't know how to start.  Please give hints.

Comment: What topology do we impose on this group of matrices?

Comment: It is one of the problems in our practice packet and it doesn't specify the topology.

Comment: Well, unless we can figure out what an "open set of matrices" would be, we can't answer any topological questions. We could just apply the Euclidean metric to $\Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$, which is what I think they're going for.

Comment: You may find the Cartan decomposition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition#Cartan_decomposition_on_the_Lie_group_level) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we take matrices under the usual norm, i.e. for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$:
$$
\|A\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i,j = 1}^n |A_{ij}|^2}
$$
we can show that the Euclidean matrix group is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times S^1$.  This form should be easier to work with.

In other words, show that
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(z) & \sin(z) & x \\
-\sin(z) & \cos(z)& y \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right) \mapsto (x,y,(\cos z,\sin z))
$$
Defines a homeomorphism from the matrix group to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times S^1$.

---

Showing that the above is a continuous map: in fact, it's easier to use the (topologically equivalent) norms
$$
\|A\| =\sum_{i,j = 1}^n |A_{ij}|; \qquad
\|(a,b,(c,d))\| = |a| + |b| + |c| + |d|
$$

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two matrices with $\|A_1 - A_2\| < \epsilon$.  That is,
$$
|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2| + 2 |\cos(z_1) - \cos(z_2)| + 2|\sin(z_1) - \sin(z_2)| < \epsilon
$$
We then have
$$
\|f(A_1) - f(A_2)\| = \\
|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2| + |\cos(z_1) - \cos(z_2)| + |\sin(z_1) - \sin(z_2)| <\\
|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2| + 2 |\cos(z_1) - \cos(z_2)| + 2|\sin(z_1) - \sin(z_2)| < \epsilon
$$
So, $\|A_1 - A_2\| < \epsilon \implies  \|f(A_1) - f(A_2)\| < \epsilon$.  Thus, $f$ is a (uniformly) continuous function.

Comment: I don't understand anything because we didn't cover Lie groups so please could u do it in detail.

Comment: @Lusin no Lie-stuff is required here.  See my latest edit.  Does that clear anything up?

Comment: I have seen it is bijective, but not other stuffs, so could you please show me show this function is continuous so that i can use same idea to show inverse is continuous.

Comment: @Lusin see my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

The upper left $2 \times 2$-block parameterizes a familiar space, call it $X$. The $(x,y)$-entries give a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The group is homeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb{R}^2$ and therefore the fundamental group of the Euclidean group is isomorphic to $\pi_1(X)$.